# MQTTX - ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript, axios, xmlhttprequest, mqtt, fetch-api

I am writing a small script in the `MQTTX` Script section, where `JavaScript` is being used. The code is as follows:

```js
async function handlePayload(value, msgType, index) {
  const object = value
  const d = new Date();
  let time = d.getTime();
  const date = new Date(time);

  // Get the hours and minutes
  const hours = date.getUTCHours();
  const minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
  const seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
  const timeX = `${hours + 1}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  object.time = timeX
  object.message = "⚠️ Check out our new Raffle! ⚠️";

  const postData = {
    included_segments: ["Total Subscriptions"],
    app_id: ONES_APP_ID,
    contents: { en: "Something went wrong" },
    headings: { en: "❌ - Error" },
    data: { custom_data: "some_value" },
   android_channel_id: ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID,
   ios_sound: "alarm.wav"
  };

  if (msgType === "publish" && object.type === "error") {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(postData),
        headers: {
          "Authorization": REST_API_KEY,
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
  }

  return JSON.stringify(object);
}
```

The whole script works except the `fetch`, even better not only does the `fetch` not work but also the `axios` & `XMLHttpRequest` does not work. They all 3 provide an error as follows.

> ReferenceError: <fetch | axios | XMLHttpRequest> is not defined

I have asked the people at `MQTTX` but no response as of today, so i come here before you all for guidance. Or if their is any other way. The call does work in `Postman`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` is [experimental](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html#fetch) and was added in NodeJS v17.5 (and enabled at v18.0), I am guessing but it looks like MQTTX is electron based so is still running a NodeJS engine that isn't at the right level (probably v16.x).

The other libraries e.g. axios are not in scope for the sandbox the script code runs in.

You will need the MQTTX folk to answer what options are available to make HTTP requests in their script sandbox.

Comment: Oke, i will wait for a response, thank you very much!